# Examples of "Hard" Expectation Maximization other than clustering?

Tags: expectation-maximization

Are there examples of learning algorithms(other than k-means clustering) which fit the paradigm of Hard-EM?

By hard EM, I mean the variant described in [here](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dmcallester/ttic101-07/lectures/em/em.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found there is a Hard EM variant for training HMMs/PCFGs. Details can be found in [this](http://cronos.rutgers.edu/~lrr/Reprints/segmental%20k-means%20algorithm.pdf) and [this](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/scohen/acl10viterbi.pdf) paper.

You are better off searching for Viterbi Training instead of Hard EM. The community uses this variant of EM under different names; it is rarely referred to as Hard EM (until recently).

Will be adding more details if I find something relevant.